# How can I get the corresponding features back?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

I converted two columns of a pandas dataframe into numpy arrays to use as the features and labels for a machine learning problem.

Code:

```
train_index, test_index = next(iter(ShuffleSplit(len(labels), train_size=0.2, test_size=0.80, random_state=42)))

features_train, features_test, = X[train_index], X[test_index]
labels_train, labels_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index]

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
pred = clf.predict(features)
print pred
```

Features is currently an array of frequency counts (I used a CountVectorizer earlier to fit and transform my original pandas dataframe column).  I have the full list of labels stored as pred, but I would like the corresponding feature to each label, so that I may return the list of labels to my pandas dataframe.

Comment: Here you are getting two sets of rows (train and test) and putting the resulting values into the variables features_*. It looks like you're calling your samples, features. This is a big no-no in machine learning! Features are the attributes of your dataset, usually the columns, so reading this code is very confusing. BUT, since you predict on "features" (which i suppose is your matrix of (samples, features), then the resulting array pred should be ordered correctly and you can put it straight back into your dataframe.

Comment: Hmm. This makes sense, but my samples essentially are my features, since I do not have any other information on them besides what labels I would like them to have (which are similar to the features/samples); I am using this ML process as a way to consolidate the samples into corresponding labels. Can I keep my code the same and just use @lejlot 's answer and be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering of predictions is the same as passed data (and as @Ulf pointed out - you are incorrectly using term "feature" here, feature is a column of your matrix, particular object that you are counting using countvectorizer; rows are observations, samples, data-points - and this is what you currently call features). Thus in order to see sample-label pairs you can simply zip them together:

```
pred = clf.predict(features)
for sample, label in zip(features, pred):
  print sample, label
```

If you actually want to recover what each column means, your CountVectorizer is your guy. Somewhere in your code you created it

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer( ... )
```

and later used it

```
... = vectorizer.fit_transform( ... )
```

now you can use it to transform your samples back through

```
pred = clf.predict(features)
for sample, label in zip(features, pred):
  print vectorizer.inverse_transform(np.array([sample])), label
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense, but my samples essentially are my features, since I do not have any other information on them besides what labels I would like them to have (which are similar to the features/samples); I am using this ML process as a way to consolidate the samples into corresponding labels. Can I keep my code the same and just use  your answer and be OK?

Comment: This is just about the names, convention,  not actual issue. You are good to go.